# PHP export to excel doesn't display UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to export data to excel via a sql query. It works but doesn't display the language.

I'm using SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8  but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```html
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";

$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8",$Connect); 

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    

$file_ending = "xls";

//header info for browser
header('Content-Encoding: TIS620');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }

        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        $schema_insert = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($schema_insert, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $schema_insert);
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
```

The field have alien language when this field is in my regional language.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mysql_*` interface; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Do not use `iconv()`.

Do include `SET NAMES utf8`.